# utorrent has crashed. Unable to create crash dump

Tags: utorrent

I am running windows 7 64 bit.My utorrent keeps on crashing today.

This is the error report in utorrent.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: uTorrent.exe
  Application Version:  3.2.0.27886
  Application Timestamp:    5047d5cf
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17725
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec49b8f
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00033ab3
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    4105
  Additional Information 1: ef39
  Additional Information 2: ef399910b5930f3396dd5a2c2389d552
  Additional Information 3: 4256
  Additional Information 4: 42568b71cd5ecc01bb3b93ff0c58bd63
```

Can someone help me resolve this please.

Comment: Unisnstall utorrent, reinstall utorrent.

Answer (score -3):

Kindly disable your network adapter and than launch utorrent. Than again unable your network adapter. This happens in cases when utorrent have issues with your network adapter.